# Can I use z-scores with an exponential distribution? Or is there another test statistic for these types of distributions?

Tags: probability, self-study, z-score, exponential-distribution

I have an exponential distribution for a population. $\theta = \mu = \sigma$ is known. Sample size $n$ is known. I need to find $"(<¯<)"$ for a random sample with size $n$.

I think I am supposed to use the z-score (or at least that's what I would do if it was normally distributed), but I'm not sure what to do for an exponential distribution.

If you need to know numbers to help me:

$\theta = \mu = \sigma = 50$

$a = 45$

$b = 60$

$n = 60$

If I use the z-score this is how I would do it:

P(x>45): z = (45-50)/(50/sqrt(60)) = -.77 -> 0.2794 (from table) -> .5-.2794 = .2206

P(x<60): z = (60-50)/(50/sqrt(60)) = 1.55 -> 0.4394 (from table)

.4394 + .2206 = .66

this seems a lot better intuitively

Comment: There’s a detail missing. $P(a<\theta <b)= P(45 <50<60)=1$, and I don’t think that’s what you intend to calculate. Also, an exponential distribution does not have equal mean and variance.

Comment: The data is distributed exponentially for the population distribution. I am attempting to find the probability that a random sample of size n=60 will yield a mean between 45 and 60

Comment: Okay, then you want $P(45<\bar{X}<60)$. Also, is this for a class? If so, please add the self-study tag and read its wiki. I’ll let you chew on $P(45<\bar{X}<60)$ for a little. Hint: $P(a<\bar{X}<b) = P(na<n\bar{X}<nb) = P(na <\sum_iX_i <nb)$.

Comment: I'll add the tag. So are you saying I don't use the z-score? is the z-score only for normal distributions? That is my main question. I don't need you to do it for me, just if i use the z-score and if not maybe point me in the right direction.

Comment: It would help if you showed how you’d use the z-score if the problem dealt with a normal distribution.

Comment: I would calculate the z-score with the formula for x>45 and x<60, get the values from the table in my book and subtract to find the inbetween

Comment: I meant to do that calculation in an edit to your original post. Write it out with the numbers and a final answer.

Comment: I did it and got 0.16. This intuitively does not seem correct, I would expect it to be higher

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106444/discussion-between-ethan-hennessey-and-dave).

Comment: 1. Your body text says "$P(a<X<b)$" (which is a question about an *exponential* random variable) but your comments are discussing "$P(a<\bar{X}<b)$" - quite a different proposition. Please clarify your question. 2. Note that it's possible to calculate such a probability exactly (given a gamma-cdf function) - or you might use a normal approximation, particularly if the interval is not in the far tail (though it's not clear why you would bother when the exact answer is so easy).

Answer (score 1):

From your work with z-scores, it seems clear than you want
to find $P(45 < \bar X < 60),$ where $\bar X$ is the mean of
a sample of size $n = 60$ from an exponential distribution
with mean $\mu = 50,$ rate $\lambda = 1/50 = 0.02.$

**Normal approximation.** You can get a useful rough approximation by assuming that
$\bar X$ is approximately normally distributed.
It is true that $E(\bar X) = 50,\,$ $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n
= 50^2/60 = 41.67,\,$ and $SD(\bar X) =6.455.$
If it were exactly true that $\bar X \sim 
\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50, \sigma =6.455),$ then $P(45 < \bar X < 60) =0.720,$ according to the following computation in R. (Your method of standardizing and using printed tables of the standard normal CDF will get very nearly the same answer, if you use the results of the table properly.)

```
diff(pnorm(c(45,60), 50, 6.455))
[1] 0.7200416
```

The Central Limit Theorem provides accurate results for
sufficiently large $n.$ However, the mean of $n=60$ exponential observations is still noticeably skewed to the right. A normal approximation would work better for the
mean of a sample twice as large.

**Exact computation using a gamma distribution.** An exact solution is available, as follows. One can
show that $\bar X/\mu \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(n, n),$ so
$P(0.9 = 45/50 < \bar X/\mu < 60/50 = 1.2) = 0.709,$ according
to the following computation in R.

```
diff(pgamma(c(.9, 1.2), 60, 60)
[1] 0.7090068
```

**Simulating the sum of exponential observations.** Also, the following simulation of a million averages of 60 such
exponential random variables gives the same answer, within the margin of simulation error. (The simulation should be accurate
to two or three decimal places.)

```
set.seed(2020)    # for reproducibility
a = replicate(10^6, mean(rexp(60,1/50)))
mean(45 < a & a < 60)
[1] 0.708975      # aprx 0.709
2^sd(45 < a & a < 60)/1000
[1] 0.001370056   # aprx 95% margin of sim error
```

Below is a histogram of simulated values of $\bar X/50$ along
with the density function (black) of its exact gamma distribution
and the density function (broken red) of its approximate normal distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(50/50, 6.455/50).$
(The gamma distribution is slightly right-skewed and the normal distribution is symmetrical.)

[image]